# I am confuse between both of them which one is the best GoogleApiClient or FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, android-maps, android-googleapiclient, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am confuse between both of them which one is the best GoogleApiClient or FusedLocationProviderClient. Some people use GoogleApiClient and some use FusedLocationProviderClient.I am confuse between both of them which one is the best  I am beginer i am very confuse please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GoogleApiClient ("Google API Client") object to access the Google APIs provided in the Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-In, Games,  Drive and Location also). So in order to get the location, one first needs to connect to google play services which requires you to write some boiler plate code to manage the connection and can sometimes result in error. Even if you are not using location services, you need to connect to google play services.

FusedLocationProviderClient provides improved and simpler apis to provide location functionality to your app with the help of just a listener. It handles the connection by itself. The new API will automatically resolve certain connection failures for you, so you don't need to write code that for things like prompting the user to update Google Play services.

Comment: Thank you so much for your  reply. It solve my confusion!